# Proper technical/ financial term for CDs, DVDs, and USB drives

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm just curious --

In a business setting with native English and non-native English speakers. Most revenue is software based, but there is a significant category that includes physical CDs, DVDs, and USB drives (containing software).

Currently it's called "physical devices" -- however in a financial book, in isolation, this might conjure up the idea of computers & IT resources, especially since it's usually discussed in terms of cost.

Is a "device" the proper term for CD/ DVD/ and USB sticks?

I would imagine personally that "physical media" is a more accurate term - but am I just being pedantic? Or is the idea that a CD is a "device" simply incorrect?

Example sentence: "These are are wholesale costs for blank CDs and DVDs -- they fall under our Sales/ Costs of ____" (Physical Devices, Physical Media, ??)

Comment: These are data carriers.

Comment: Those are all examples of external storage. Physical media refers to cabling.

Comment: @jimm101 -- in all my years in the business, I've never heard cabling  called _physical media_.  The term physical media came into use (as far as I can remember) when the option of delivering data via a network became a reality.  As in, _you can get the new software over the network or on physical media._

Comment: @RogerSinasohn In the networking world, it's whether you're using copper, fiber, etc., and that goes back decades.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_media

Comment: @jimm101 -- Huh.  I'll admit that my networking experience is pretty much limited to the unfinished wiring poking out of holes in the wall all over my house.  Now I've learned something new.  On the software side of things, however, media refers to the discs (and memory sticks) you put your software on.  Consider [Super**Media**Store.com](https://www.supermediastore.com/) which has product categories including _Blank CD/DVD Media_ (the actual discs) and _Media Accessories_ (cases, labels, and mailers, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to the flat circles that hold data, software, music, and movies, along with flash memory that plugs into a USB port, then, collectively, they would indeed be called ***media***.  The Oxford Dictionaries has this definition of ***medium*** (the singular form of *media*):

> ***[medium](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/medium)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 3. A particular form of storage material for computer files, such as magnetic tape or discs.

Magtape and disks (I've always argued that magnetic disks, both hard disks and floppy disks have a *K* while CDs -- Compact Discs -- and the like are discs with a *C*) are less common these days, but this definition would definitely be used for CDs, DVDs, and flash drives/cards.

If you want to be specific about what they'll be used for, you could call them *storage media* and if you want to highlight that your software will not be transmitted via the internet or other network, then *physical media* would work.

Comment: *Removable media* is the specific term for anything that contains data and which can be easily carried from one computer to another.

Comment: @JasonBassford -- it all depends on context.  Consider [Physical Media — Who needs it?](https://medium.com/@darkuni/physical-media-who-needs-it-36de21a4e10c) and [5 reasons why you should collect physical media](https://gemr.com/blog/collect-physical-media/).  A lot of people still prefer physical media over streaming: [eBay Data Reveals Resurgence of Physical Media](https://www.ebayinc.com/stories/news/ebay-data-reveals-resurgence-of-physical-media/).  The National Archives preserves [a lot of physical media](https://www.archives.gov/preservation/products/definitions/analog.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

The expression I'd use is **(external) storage device**.

Device alone can refer to a lot more than what you're describing: computers, phones, fax machines, etc. Just think of the acronym BYOD. Saying it's a "*physical* device" doesn't clear this up.

> #### Storage Device
>
> Any media, permanently attached or transportable, capable of storing electronic information.
>
> Examples:
>
> - hard drive
> - CD-ROM
> - DVD-ROM
> - flash media
> - "thumb" drive
> - memory stick
> - [...]
>
> <sub>[UCSF](https://it.ucsf.edu/policies/definition-and-types-storage-devices)</sub>